# Is there a default implementation for a readonly stream in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I need to craft a `Stream` that will only support `Read()` operation - the stream will be readonly and non-seekable. Still I have to implement a lot of properties such as `Position` (which will throw a `NotImplementedException`) - that's a lot of boilerplate code.

Is there perhaps some standard implementation for such stream where I only need to `override` the `Read()` operation?

Comment: Inherited from any Stream and override `CanWrite` and `CanSeek` to return false.

Comment: Are you delegating to another stream, or do you already have all the data? `MemoryStream` allows you to create a read-only version (although it *is* seekable).

Comment: @JonSkeet: Good thing it is not `sealed`, so you can override `CanSeek `there :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have all the data but inheriting from `MemoryStream` would mean that my class is a flavor of `MemoryStream` which it is really not.

Comment: @sharptooth: Well if it's returning data that's stored in memory, that sounds like it really *is* a flavour of `MemoryStream`. You can still return it as a `Stream` from whatever method creates it, of course.

Comment: You can chain Stream objects together easily, the Read() method simply calls the previous stream's Read() method.  Compare to BufferedStream, without the buffer.  Encapsulation, not inheritance, pass the previous stream reference through the constructor.  You don't care what flavor stream that is, just that it is readable.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sure, but I'll still have to override a gazillion of stuff to return `false` or throw a `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: "Gazillion" is unnecessary hyperbole of course.  It is simple delegation, every member is a single line of code.  If it takes you longer to implement the members than it took you to wait for the answer then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, it's ten one-liners and none of them I really need but I'm required to have them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the constructor `new MemorySream(byte[] buffer, bool writeable)` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_IO_MemoryStream__ctor_System_Byte___System_Boolean_)).

Setting the `writeable` parameter to `false` will make the stream readonly.

Answer (score 12):

Such a stream does not exist in the BCL. You have to write it. In my life I have implemented about a dozen such streams and it is not too bad. The 2nd one is much easier because you can use the first one as a template.

I recommend that you inherit from `Stream` and not from some other stream. If you were inheriting from `MemoryStream` you'd abuse inheritance to save code which is not its primary purpose. Your derived stream would not work like a `MemoryStream` and it *is-not* a `MemoryStream`.

Prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: +1 "If you were inheriting from MemoryStream you'd abuse inheritance to save code which is not its primary purpose.". That's what I was tempted to do.